# Finding the minimum in an array

Tags: java

I have some problems with this code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Function{
    public static void main(String[] Problem) {
        int i, continut, minim = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type the maximum number of element:");
        continut = in.nextInt();
        int array[] = new int[continut];
        for (i = 0; i < continut; i++) {
            array[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        for (i = 0; i < continut; i++) {
            if (array[i] < minim) {
                minim = array[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.print(minim);
    }
}
```

I don't understand why after I run this program the output always gives me minim=0.

Answer (score 3):

Your current `minim` is set to `0` and you are probably providing bigger numbers which means that minimum will never be replaced by any smaller number.

To avoid this problem you can initialize `minim` with

1. first value from user,
2. maximal possible integer `minim = Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 1):

```
minim=Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

Instead of 0 should do the work. This way, youre pretty much sure the first value testes is below `minim`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 0 you can initialize it with the first element of array like

```
minim=array[0];
```

Now you can easily check minimum from that array!

Answer (score 0):

Assign the first input to `minim`, and iterate from the 2nd to compare against `minim` and update:

```
int minim = array[0];
for (i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] < minim) {
        minim = array[i];
    }
}
```

However, this requires that there are at least one elements.
In fact if there are no elements, finding the minimum doesn't make sense.
So it's good to add input validation:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Type the maximum number of element:");
    continut = in.nextInt();
    if (contitut > 0) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Invalid input: please enter an integer > 0");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to store the first value of your array as `minim`. Then you have to check that value against the others, if other values are smaller than `minim` then replace that minim with that number.

You can do that by adding

```
minim = array[0];
```

before your code